# Merge files from Data lake store

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a package that daily imports a file to Data lake store. So that is the same file with different values(same columns etc). My idea is to merge those files into a single file on Data lake, for a monthly report. I want to investigate U-SQL, so my question is:
Is that possible to do with U-SQL?
If its not possible is there any other options to do that?

Comment: i am not involed in Azure Database yet, but i can imagine that the Data Tools from Microsoft could create an application for that. May try it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try with this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621340.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: would love to see your solution to this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easily possible to merge records from two files and write a new file. Here are the steps

1. Read all of the new file using EXTRACT
2. Read all the records of the current master file using EXTRACT
3. Use UNION ALL to merge the records: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621340.aspx
4. Write output to master file using OUTPUT statement

For a quick U-SQL tutorial go here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-get-started

Comment: i have a bunch of CSV files in a directory, they all have a mask `1_myfile1.csv` , `1_myfile2.csv` `1_myfile3.csv`  --- how do i merge all the `1_*csv` files?

Comment: you could simply use wildcard, why do you need UNION ALL? you dont